# Privatemsg module shows admin and myself in autocomplete

Tags: ajax, privatemsg

I am using Drupal 7. In the [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module my autocomplete shows myself and admin. How can I disable displaying the user who's logged in in the autocomplete and disable displaying admin?

Answer (score 1):

**Put this code in your template.php file**

```
function yourtheme-name_query_privatemsg_autocomplete_alter($query) {
  global $user;
  $query-> condition('u.uid' , $user->uid, '<>');
}
```